# Accessing an custom made dynamic class properties throws errors - kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make an dynamic class with GridLayout in .kv file, and access it in the code to add widgets to it, but trying to access anything on it even if it the length of it's children list throws errors.

.kv file

```
<Row@GridLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y : None
    height: self.minimum_height
    row_default_height: 30
    spacing: [2, 2]
```

python script

```
class Row(GridLayout):
    pass

print(len(Row.children))
```

I get object of type 'kivy.properties.ListProperty' has no len(), so what's wrong here?

Comment: The `children` attribute of the `Row` class is a `ListProperty`. If you want to access the `children` of an actual instance of the `Row` class, you must do something like `print(len(row_instance.children))` where `row_instance` is an instance of the `Row` class.

Comment: I got it now, so for example i create an instance with a var and alwasy use that var as instance, so row = Row(), and then i use row.children